# Подскажите ,что не так?Когда программа выводит результат ,то в начале показывает знак вопроса либо не то что нужно

Tags: c

Задание: увеличить числа в строчке вдвое

```
Original:fgg 55 hhj 66
Result:�fgg 110 hhj 132
Либо так: 
Original:
gjugfujf
Result:
�gjugfujf 152 fhj gjugfujf 152 fhj 112 92928
```

```
int letters(char ch);
char test[]=" ";
char orig[81],result[81],dig[13];
int radix=10;

    printf("Будь ласка введіть рядок\n");
    printf("Введіть рядок,слова*англійські* та цифри повинні бути записані через пробіли: \n");
    ch = gets(test);
    
        char *p;int d;
        strcpy(orig,test);
        p=strtok(test," ");
        while (p != NULL)
        {if ((d=atol(p))==0)
           {strcat(result,p);strcat(result," ");}
        else{sprintf(dig,"%d",d*2);strcat(result,dig);strcat(result," ");}
        p=strtok(NULL," ");}
        printf("Original:%s\nResult:%s\n",orig,result);
    
  
    ch = getchar(); 
    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `gets` использует буфер `test` и записывает туда данные. Так как у вас буфер очень маленький `char test[]=" ";` происходит переполнение и порча памяти. Эта функция считается устаревшей, и рекомендуется использовать другую, в которой аргументом задаётся предельный размер буфера.

Во первых задайте буфер побольше и используйте `fgets` вместо `gets` :

```
enum { bufsize = 80 } ;
char test [ bufsize ] ;

fgets ( test , bufsize , stdin ) ;

// стирание буквы перевода строки
test[strlen(test)-1] = '\00';
```

Comment: Как исправить ,то :, когда ввожу строку с цыфр то неправильно делает , а если с букв то работает?

Comment: не понимаю проблему, может быть **подробно** опишете в другом вопросе?

Comment: Ввод: 55 get 77

Comment: Вывод : 110  20 Или ввод : get 55 77 Вывод : get 110 152